# GAE as service provider for Desktop App (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, google-app-engine

I'm new to Google App Engine.
I know the Cloud concept and I know a bit about the API and Storage of GAE.

Problem:
One Desktop application (Java, Swing) needs some services. These services should be given to the app via HTTP/HTTPS.

For example the app sends some parameters and receive a result (String(s)).

Is GAE good for providing the services to the App?
If so, What is the best point to start?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best point to start is the documentation: http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/java/overview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could create a web service and put it on GAE. So that could be way how to use it from your Swing app.

There is no reason why this approach shouldn't work.

Comment: Java web-services can be deployed on GAE without any modifications?

Comment: @ehsun7b No, but luckily google **documented** all that stuff - who'd have thought?